# Shaving head on umrah

Tags: umrah

As I have read online that minimum age for umrah is 12 years old, we are taking our kids which are 3 and 7, do we need to shave their heads?

Or should we leave it and teach them when they are minium 12 then they can?

Comment: There is no minimum age for umrah in Islam.